# responsive button group container

Tags: html, css, sass

I have two buttons in a row in a grey container , in mobile view I want to have a responsive container and its height be somehow that all buttons can place well in it , button number 2 can be removed for some cases so height can not be fixed and may change if we have 1 button or two

```
 .selectContainer {
     top: 0;
     height: 95px;
     position: sticky;
     z-index: 9999;
     padding: 1.4em;
     width: 100%;
     background: rgb(239, 239, 239);
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your design :

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but it did not fix the issue :(